# Texture in the Unity Resources path doesn't load on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game for Android using Unity, and I need load some texture from the Resources path. But this only works in the editor, and when I build the project for Android, the image doesn't load.

My code looks like this:

```
public void setTipTextTexture(string texture){ 
    texture = "TipTexts/" + texture; 
    this.tipTexture = Resources.Load(texture) as Texture; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us how you're loading them.

Comment: I'm loading like this:


public void setTipTextTexture(string texture){
  
  texture = "TipTexts/" + texture;
    
  this.tipTexture = Resources.Load(texture) as Texture;
 
}

Comment: Have you tried other build types to verify the problem is Android specific?

Comment: yes, I tried on IOs and web, but only web works, and in the IOs don't works too :(

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange.  Can you verify that `Resources.Load(texture) as Texture` is returning `null`  If not, it might point to a rendering issue.  If so, I'm stumped.  Everything in `Resources` should copy over.

Comment: Haha it's right now. I didn't know what happened. I didn't change anything in the code, and started to load simply. 

So, thanks for the helps.